# Ruby - Zookeeper gem version wrong number of arguments (3 for 4) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, apache-zookeeper

I have installed ruby 2.0.0p195 and following gem

```
gem install net-ssh

gem install rdoc

gem install zookeeper

Ruby Zookeeper client installed successfully (ver - 1.4.4)
```

But when I execute the sample ruby script to check the node exists and create node on zookeeper:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zookeeper'

z = Zookeeper.new("localhost:2181")
if !z.exists("/app", :watch => true)
        z.create("/app","app root node",:mode => :ephemeral)
end
z.get_children(:path => "/")
```

...it throws following error.

```
zookeeper-1.4.4/lib/zookeeper/continuation.rb:172:in `zkrb_exists': wrong number of arguments (3 for 4) (ArgumentError)
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/zookeeper-1.4.4/lib/zookeeper/continuation.rb:172:in `submit'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/zookeeper-1.4.4/ext/c_zookeeper.rb:303:in `submit_pending_calls'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/zookeeper-1.4.4/ext/c_zookeeper.rb:261:in `event_thread_body'
```

Can anyone please help me on resolving this problem?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: require 'rubygems'
require 'zookeeper'

z = Zookeeper.new("localhost:2181")
if !z.exists("/app", :watch => true)
        z.create("/app","app root node",:mode => :ephemeral)
end
z.get_children(:path => "/")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> require "rubygems"
>
> require "zk"
>
> zk = ZK.new
>
> ZK.open('localhost:2181') do |zk|
> if !zk.exists?('/root')
>
> ```
>    zk.create("/root", :data => "foo")
> ```
>
> end
>
> end

Started using zk instead of zookeeper gems. Its working fine now, but not sure about exact solution for above argument error.

Answer (score 0):

Using ZK, it's much more friendly and well-documented. The Zookeeper gem is intended as a low-level driver layer, ZK is intended for application writing.